# VB.NET text animation

Tags: vb.net, animation

I am doing a scrolling text animation with VS2010 and Windows 7. I have a textbox, label and a button, of course a timer to make this work. following is the code I put in timer.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Label1.Text = TextBox1.Text
    Timer1.Interval = 1000
    Timer1.Start()

End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    'Dim txtBuffer As String = TextBox1.Text
    Label1.Text = Label1.Text
    If Len(Label1.Text) <> 0 Then
        Label1.Text = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right(Label1.Text, (Len(Label1.Text) - 1))
    Else
        Timer1.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub
```

My problem is when you input a certain amount of space at the start of string, the scrolling animation is kind of strange. It will not showing the string moving from right side into the label, but only show the whole string at once then start scrolling out of the left boundary of the label.

I am using fixed length of label, my purpose is to simulate a message board, so the text can be scrolled into the msg box from right side and moving out from left.

I debuged each time the timer was triggered and the head of string which is a certain amount of spaces does go away one by one. But I didn't see the expected animation on the label.

The size of label is 7 upper case letters' width and AutoSize property is false. If in the textbox you input is "[7 space] ABCDEFG", then you would expect the scrolling effect would be "[7 space]"->"[6 space]A"->"[5 space]AB"-> "[4 space]ABC"->...->"ABCDEFG"->"BCDEFG"->"CDEFG"->...->"". But you won't get it. All you will get is "[7 space]" for a while, then all of a sudden, "ABCDEFG" appears, then the letters go away one by one. The string is not looks like it slides in from the right side of label area.

I don't know if anyone can help on that or maybe have a better idea to realize that animation? Thanks!

Comment: I think you need to give us more code or properties that reproduces the problem.  `Label1.Text = Label1.Text` does do anything, of course.

Comment: Hi Lars Tech, I edit my question and add all the code I have. The demo program is let user can input some text into textbox, click the button, then the string will start scrolling at a label, I put there. And if the text input is non-space headed, then everything works fine. Thanks for your viewing.

Comment: Is the label's AutoSize property set to true?  What is the size of the label control?  What is the "text" value you use that causes this issue?  Your posted code seems to work, so I'm not seeing any weirdness.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's probably easier to just move a label inside a panel control than trying to figure out character measurements, etc, in order to get the text to *start* on the right side and then move left:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  Label1.AutoSize = True
  Label1.Text = TextBox1.Text
  Label1.Parent = Panel1
  Label1.Location = New Point(Panel1.ClientSize.Width, _
                              Panel1.ClientSize.Height / 2 - (Label1.Height / 2))
  Timer1.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
  If Label1.Right < 0 Then
    Label1.Left = Panel1.ClientSize.Width
  Else
    Label1.Left -= 10
  End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue.  I solved using a timer and calculating the textbox size to move the text (right to left) until the left border. The idea is move the text from right to left and when the text ends before fill the textbox, complete the text with same blank spaces and restart showing the text.

```
Private _textToDisplay As String = "12345"
Private _Showing As String = ""
Private _avrchar As Integer = 0

Private Sub Showing_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TickerTimer.Tick
    Try

        If _Showing.Count < _textToDisplay.Count And _Showing.Count > 0 Then
            _Showing = _textToDisplay.Substring(0, _Showing.Length + 1)
        ElseIf _Showing.Count < _textToDisplay.Count And _Showing.Count = 0 Then
            _Showing = _textToDisplay.Substring(0, 1)
        ElseIf _Showing.Count < _avrchar Then
            _Showing = " " + _Showing
        Else
            _Showing = ""
        End If
        textTicker.Text = _Showing

    Catch ex As Exception

        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Function NumberfitCharsInTextBox(tb As TextBox) As Integer
    Dim avgW As Integer = 0
    Dim avgH As Integer = 0
    Dim avg As Size
    For i As Integer = 65 To 90
        avg = TextRenderer.MeasureText(CChar(ChrW(i)).ToString(), textTicker.Font)
        avgH += avg.Height
        avgW += avg.Width
    Next
    Return CInt((((45 * textTicker.Width) / avgW) * ((45 * textTicker.Height) / avgH)))
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this very small and interesting implementation.Take a look.

```
Public Class Start
    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Label1.Left -= 10
        If Label1.Left <= -Width Then
            Label1.Left = Width
        End If
    End Sub


    Private Sub Start_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Label1.AutoSize = True
        Timer1.Start()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Did you find this anywhere in particular? If so, please attribute it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If the label size is fixed and  if it located at fixed place and just the text scroll in or out from left to right or right to left seems to be a better animation for applications.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Timer1.Interval = 1
    Label1.Left = Label1.Left - 1
    If Label1.Right = 0 Then
        Label1.Left = Me.Width + 1
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Label1.AutoSize = True
End Sub
End Class
```